# 2 parameterized where clauses in a single query (not 'where _ and _')

Tags: c#, oracle, common-table-expression, dapper, query-builder

Can parameterizing 2 different `where` clauses (non contiguous) in a single query be done in `dapper`?

Sample SQL query as `C# property`

```
private string GetSalesRepToCustomer => @"
  WITH SALES_REP_FILTERED AS (
    SELECT
      SALES_REP_ID
    FROM
      SALES_REP
    /**where**/     /* 1st where clause. */
  )
  SELECT
    A.SALES_REP_ID,
    B.CUSTOMER_ID
  FROM
    SALES_REP_FILTERED A LEFT JOIN
    CUSTOMER           B   ON A.SALES_REP_ID = B.SALES_REP_ID
  /**where**/     /* 2nd where clause */
";
```

C# parameterization **not working**, *illustration purposes*.

```
SqlTemplate queryTemplate = new SqlBuilder()
  .where("SALES_REP_ID = :SALES_REP_ID")

  // this 2nd 'where' is illustrative.
  // In actual an 'and' clause is created.
  // My goal is to have a secondary/non contiguous 'where' clause in the same query.
  .where("CUSTOMER_ID  IN :CUSTOMER_ID")
  .AddTemplate(GetSalesRepToCustomer);

var conn = new OracleConnection();
var queryResults = conn.Query(
  queryTemplate.RawSql,
  new { SALES_REP_ID = 2021, CUSTOMER_ID = new int[] {11, 22, 33}}
);
```

Context and reasoning of what I want to achieve:

1. Read online (Cant recall where. Probably on stackoverflow) the incentive(s) for `dapper` query parameterization and would like to stick/follow to this recommended practice.
2. I could split the query up into 2 and make separate round trips to the DB. But there are performance and `IO` payoffs/benefits when executed as a single query.
3. My last option is to in line the `where` clauses in `SQL`. But this probably would negate the benefits of `dapper` parameterization? `I.e.`

```
private string GetSalesRepToCustomer => @"
  WITH SALES_REP_FILTERED AS (
    SELECT
      SALES_REP_ID
    FROM
      SALES_REP
    where SALES_REP_ID = :SALES_REP_ID
  )
  SELECT
    A.SALES_REP_ID,
    B.CUSTOMER_ID
  FROM
    SALES_REP_FILTERED A LEFT JOIN
    CUSTOMER           B   ON A.SALES_REP_ID = B.SALES_REP_ID
  WHERE CUSTOMER_ID IN :CUSTOMER_ID
";
```

And the `where` parameterization is taken out.

```
SqlTemplate queryTemplate = new SqlBuilder()
    // No parameterized where clauses. So also no dapper performance improvements?
    .AddTemplate(GetSalesRepToCustomer);

var conn = new OracleConnection();
var queryResults = conn.Query(
  queryTemplate.RawSql,
  new { SALES_REP_ID = 2021, CUSTOMER_ID = new int[] {11, 22, 33}}
);
```

Comment: What does *not working* actually mean?

Comment: It's not two queries; it's a common table expression and a query that uses it - which is one query. It has a syntax error too, by the way - comma is not expected after the final bracket on a WITH clause (or chain of with clauses)

Comment: @CaiusJard noted and fixed on the SQL syntax errors. On the 2 queries part, I'm assuming you're referring to pt.2? For that, I meant to express that I could break up the CTE into 2 separate queries (not my goal). As for the "Not working" code block, I wanted to express what I want to achieve via the code illustration and not in the sense that the code doesn't execute. In fact, it is able to run. But the executed results are not what I intended.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: If the optimizer is doing it's job right, it optimizes the entire query *as a whole*. It can freely move predicates around as it sees fit (providing the results are logically consistent). In SQL, you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*, so it doesn't matter which `WHERE` clause particular predicates appear in (in this case)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I agree with your statement on SQL. But what I'm trying to find (or clarify) and achieve (2 non contiguous 'where'), is Dapper's optimization for parameterization and not so on the SQL part. As mentioned I've read about it somewhere online but can't really recall where off the cuff. Back to your statement on SQL, I believe SQL optimizers are unable to move predicates of different CTE blocks around? (at least in the oracle context),

Comment: You seem to have some sort of misconception. You're passing parameters to dapper with the anonymous type `new {...}`, applying them to query returned by RawSql. In fact you have no real need for the SqlBuilder as you are just throwing away what it's doing... and since it's where clauses are appended and anded at the end anyways the query is better off written as it is in your last example (where I've already pointed out you are properly parameterizing)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, this should be fine:

```
var conn = new OracleConnection();
var sql = @"
  WITH SALES_REP_FILTERED AS (
    SELECT
      SALES_REP_ID
    FROM
      SALES_REP
    where SALES_REP_ID = :SALES_REP_ID
  )
  SELECT
    A.SALES_REP_ID,
    B.CUSTOMER_ID
  FROM
    SALES_REP_FILTERED A LEFT JOIN
    CUSTOMER           B   ON A.SALES_REP_ID = B.SALES_REP_ID
  WHERE CUSTOMER_ID IN :CUSTOMER_ID
";
var queryResults = conn.Query<SOME_TYPE>(
  sql,
  new { SALES_REP_ID = 2021, CUSTOMER_ID = new int[] {11, 22, 33}}
);
```

But your SQL could also be written as:

```
  SELECT
    A.SALES_REP_ID,
    B.CUSTOMER_ID
  FROM
    SALES_REP SR
    LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER C   ON SR.SALES_REP_ID = C.SALES_REP_ID
  WHERE 
    C.CUSTOMER_ID IN :CUSTOMER_ID AND
    SR.SALES_REP_ID = :SALES_REP_ID
```

If you pass 3 customer IDs, then dapper will rewrite your WHERE clause to be:

```
WHERE C.CUSTOMER_ID IN (:CUSTOMER_ID1, :CUSTOMER_ID2, :CUSTOMER_ID3) AND
```

and it will populate the command's parameters collection with the three parameters populated with the values supplied

Comment: Noted on the query rewrite part. In that manner, query performance should be reliant on the table columns indexation for optimizations. With CTE, optimization is slightly more explicit with SQL as they are executed in sequential parts/blocks of the CTE (I think). So with my SALES_REP records narrowed down, the left join should be more efficient/productive.

Comment: I'm not certain I would agree, but you can get oracle to tell you; do an *explain plan* for both forms of the query to get the db to tell youhow it will execute them. I'd fully expect a sophisticated optimizer would plan these two queries identically